# Express "There exists a domestic car that is badly made" symbolically

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm taking the "[Introduction to Mathematical Thinking](https://www.coursera.org/learn/mathematical-thinking)" course by professor Keith Devlin on Coursera.

In the course, he mentions that:

The statement `"All domestic cars are badly made"` can be expressed symbolically as

**∀x [D(x) ⇒ M(x)]**, in which

- **D(x)** means car x is domestic
- **M(x)** means car x is badly made

However, this makes me wonder about a similar statement: `"There exists a domestic car that is badly made"`?

- It seems natural that it should be **∃x [D(x) ⇒ M(x)]**
- However, from a later lecture, it seems the correct symbolic representation of this statement should be **∃x [D(x) ∧ M(x)]**
- This is consistent with a point that the professor made in the course, which is ∃ statements with ⇒ are weak (since they could be true if you could find an x whose antecedent is false, for example, a car that is not domestic). Therefore, we should be suspicious when they occurs in our formulation.
- Yet, I still can't find a convincing reason why ∃x [D(x) ⇒ M(x)] is incorrect, since it naturally seems like the analog of the ∀x [D(x) ⇒ M(x)] statement, just with ∃ to replace ∀.

Therefore, if you have a convincing reason why ∃x [D(x) ⇒ M(x)] is incorrect, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Your "natural" formulation means "There exists a car that is not both domestic and non-badly made," which is not quite the same thing.  ($D(x) \Rightarrow M(x)$ admits of three possibilities: (a) not $D(x)$ and not $M(x)$; (b) not $D(x)$ and (yes) $M(x)$; and (c) $D(x)$ and $M(x)$.  Only $D(x)$ and not $M(x)$ is excluded.)

Comment: $A\implies B$ is equivalent to $\lnot A\lor B$ so your statement would be there exists a car that is either not domestic or is badly made. That is weaker than there exists a domestic car that is badly made.

Comment: $\exists x(A(x)\implies B(x))$ is sadly a somewhat useless statement. It's the negation of $\forall x(A(x)\land\lnot B(x))$, but a bit more opaque than just writing the negation directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write down the meanings of all four relevant statements:

(1) $\forall x\ [D(x) \implies M(x)]$. This means:

> All cars have the following property: If it is domestic, then it is poorly made.

This is the same as saying: Every domestic car is poorly made.

(2) $\forall x\ [D(x) \wedge M(x)]$. This means:

> All cars are domestic and poorly made.

(3) $\exists x\ [D(x) \implies M(x)]$. This means:

> There exists a car with the following property: If it is domestic, then it is poorly made.

As folks in the comments have mentioned, this is the same as saying: "There exists a car that is non-domestic or poorly made."

(4) $\exists x\ [D(x) \wedge M(x)]$. This means:

> There exists a car that is domestic and poorly made.

Answer (score 1):

∃x [D(x) ⇒ M(x)] doesn't work because of the following:

Suppose there is some car c that is not domestic.  Then D(c) is false, so regardless of the truth value of M(c), it is true that D(c) ⇒ M(c), since the ⇒ operator only says that the right operand is true *if* the left one is, but not that the left hand side need to be true.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can understand it more when expressing **∃x [D(x) ⇒ M(x)]** in everyday language: `"There exists a car such that if it is domestic, it is badly made"`

- This statement logically includes the case that `"There exists a car that is not domestic"` (which is or isn't badly made), since implications include cases where the antecedent is false.
- In contrast, the statement "There exists a domestic car that is badly made" doesn't necessarily imply `"There exists a car that is not domestic"` (although it could by chance be true).
- In other words, the difference between the two statement could be the inclusion of the false antecedent case, as mentioned in some of the questions and answers, as well as in the question itself.